# Return iterator to base class

Tags: c++, containers

Please suggest an effective way to iterate through base classes of a container.

```
class Base {
public:
  void bar() = 0;
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void bar() {}
};

class BaseContainer {
public:
  virtual /*iterator to Base*/ begin() = 0;
  virtual /*iterator to Base*/ end() = 0;
};

class DerivedContainer : public BaseContainer {
public:
  virtual /*iterator to Base*/ begin() { ??? }
  virtual /*iterator to Base*/ end() { ??? }
private:
  std::vector<Derived *> m_v;
};

void use_container(BaseContainer * c) {
  std::for_each(c->begin(), c->end(), [](Base * b){ b->bar(); });
}

void main() {
  DerivedContainer c;
  use_container(&c);
}
```

Commonly I do like this:

```
class BaseContainer {
  virtual int count() = 0;
  virtual Base * element(int i) = 0;
}
class DerivedContainer {
public:
  virtual int count() const { return m_v.size(); }
  virtual Base * element(int i) { return m_v.at(i); }
private:
  std::vector<Derived *> m_v;
}
void use_container(BaseContainer * c) {
  for (int i = 0; i < c->count(); i++) {
    c->element(i)->bar();
  }
}
```

But I want to use std algorithms.

Comment: Sorry what are you asking, do you want to iterate over a container as if it was a instance of it's base class or are you asking about some sort of reflection, totally lost

Comment: Is a `boost` solution acceptable?

Comment: @Yakk No boost if possible, please. C++11 is ok

Comment: @aaronman I don't see the need of reflection here. I want to iterate DerivedContainer, which should return Base * objects.

Comment: So your class' begin and end functions should return the iterators from `m_v` not sure what the confusion is

Comment: @aaronman I need them to return Base * objects. m_v iterators are for Derived. Casting from iterator<Derived *> to iterator<Base *> isn't possible, AFAIK.

Comment: write an `iterator_cast` function I guess, but also I have to say i pretty much avoid inheritance whenever I can so try to reconsider if you need it or not

Comment: @aaronman Please consider that use_container() doesn't know about Derived classes. Derived classes can implement different aspects of functionality, and use_container function just uses functions of Base interface, and should treat container as container of Base objects.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with my suggestion of an `iterator_cast` `shared_ptr` has one it's a pretty similar idea

Comment: my suggestion would be to take the `boost` design for a type erased iterator, and reimplememt it by hand.

Comment: Why not just have the container hold pointers to the base class object instead of the derived class? You can still write whatever method adds members to your derived containers to only accepts pointers to objects of the derived class.

Comment: @DariusMakaitis Then I will have to dynamic_cast them to Derived in DerivedContainer.

Comment: @aaronman Are there any resources on how to write iterator_cast? using std::vector<Base *>::iterator begin() { return iterator_cast<std::vector<Base *>::iterator>(m_v.begin()); } or something like this would be a solution